# Can't log System.Net on ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to write a Trace to my console of everything System.Net does when I make an http request but I'm getting nothing from that namespace.

My app is running self-hosted on Kestrel.

This is my appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System.Net": "Trace"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "System.Net": "Trace"        
      }
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "c:\\1\\cert.pem",
          "KeyPath": "c:\\1\\key.pem",
          "AllowInvalid": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
}
```

My program.cs:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders(); // Clear any default providers (optional)
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    logging.AddConsole(); // Add console logging
})
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {                    
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true).Build();                    

        webBuilder.UseConfiguration(config);

        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                   
    });
```

My Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallback
        };
        return handler;
    });
```

And I'm making the request like so:

```cs
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");
var response = client.Send(request);
```

Comment: I suggest you could try to remove the builder logging related codes and try the default one var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);. Since you have set the default level to trace that means all the logs will be logged at the console, no matter you set the console log or not.

Comment: I'm getting trace logging from other namespaces. Just not from System.net

Comment: I suggest you could try this "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
    },

Comment: it's b/c of the `HttpClientHander`.  I haven't figured out how to add logging back when creating your own handler.  [This blog post](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging#:~:text=how%20does%20ihttpclientfactory%20logging%20work%3F) might help.

Comment: part of the magic [happens here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8121f82d7d46118eef03a99eecbde64d8021cec7/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L131) but I haven't been able to piece it all together

Comment: @spottedmahn I finally figured it out. See the answer.
Unfortunately System.net doesn't produce low-level logging at the TCP level like it was able to do with .NET Framework because of infrastructure changes they made so it's not too helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync requests won't produce logging.

```
var response = client.Send(request);
```

Must use async requests

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```